# Maven: how to purge a custom local repository

Tags: maven

Beside the local repository at the default location, I have another local repository with snapshots of a large number of jars of some projects which do not use Maven. It is defined in `pom.xml` as follows:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots> 
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots> 
        <id>repo</id>
        <url>file:///${project.basedir}/path/to/loca/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and has a distinct `<groupId/>` so that it is not confused with any other repository. Thanks to this, the main project can be compiled fast and with up-to-date jars on any system which sees its directory.

I would like to purge old snapshots from the custom repository, but

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DlocalRepositoryPath=./path/to/local/repo
```

purges the local repository at the default location, the custom one is left untouched.

**How to purge only the repository in the custom directory?**

Comment: I do not quite unterstand your construction. Usually, you have just one local repository. You may have different repositories on your hard disk, but these are not used as local repository. Instead, one adds them to the `<repositories>` in the `settings.xml`. Could you explain in more detail what you are doing?

Comment: I added the respective contents of `pom.xml`.

Comment: Repositories in the repositories section are not called local repositories. They are like any external Nexus or Artifactory. I doubt that you can purge them from Maven directly.